# How Can I Reset my Car Movement if I return to my last respawn point?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
function OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider){
if(col.tag == "Player")
{
player.transform.position = SpawnPoint.position;

audio.PlayOneShot(Sound);
VioSign.enabled = true;
if(pauseEnabled == false){
        pauseEnabled = true;
        AudioListener.volume = 1;
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        Screen.showCursor = true;
    }
}
}
```

This is my respawnpoint script .

```
#pragma strict
var wheelFL : WheelCollider;
var wheelFR : WheelCollider;
var wheelRL : WheelCollider;
var wheelRR : WheelCollider;
var maxTorque : float = 50;

function Start(){
rigidbody.centerOfMass.y = -0.9;
}


function FixedUpdate () {
wheelRR.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelRL.motorTorque = maxTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
wheelFL.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
wheelFR.steerAngle = 20 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

}
```

Here is my Car Control Script I want to stop the car after respawning again to the respawn point . I'm having a difficult time to solve it. please help me :)

Comment: for how long do u want to stop the car?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stop the car's current movement, you can simply set its velocity to zero:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(col : Collider){
if(col.tag == "Player")
{
player.transform.position = SpawnPoint.position;
player.gameObject.rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;

audio.PlayOneShot(Sound);
VioSign.enabled = true;
if(pauseEnabled == false){
        pauseEnabled = true;
        AudioListener.volume = 1;
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        Screen.showCursor = true;
    }
}
}
```